# SVG: Bezier Curves that start at a different point than the origin point used to compute the path

Tags: svg, attributes, bezier, pathelement

I'm trying to draw a path from one `foreignObject` to another.

I'd like the path to be oriented / set according to the centre of each object, but only start some distance away from the object. For example, here are straight-lined paths from one object to two different objects: **notice that the starting point for the paths is not the same**; rather, it has been adjusted to lie on the line connecting the two objects.

[image]

If the path is a straight line, this is easy enough to achieve: simply start and end
the path at a displacement of Δr along the straight line defined by the centre points of the objects.

However, I'm not sure how one would achieve this, in the case of a Bezier curve (quadratic or cubic).

[image]

If it were possible to make part of the path transparent (*i.e.* set the stroke colour for different *parts* of the path), then one could just use the centre points and set the the first Δs px to `transparent`; however, I'm not aware of any way of doing this.

Alternatively, if it were possible to set the start and end points of a path independently of the points used to compute the path, this would address all cases (linear, Bézier quadratic or cubic).

Another option might be to use the `dash-array` property, but this would require knowing the length of the path. *e.g.* if the path length is `S`, then setting the dash-array to `x-calc(S-2x)-x` would also achieve the desired result.

**Is there any way of achieving this programmatically?**

I don't mind legwork, so even just pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question right. You want do draw a `<path>` that consist of parts with different opacities?

Comment: Can't you accomplish this by drawing order? Draw the enclosing ellipses first, then draw the connecting lines, then draw a circle with fill = background color slightly larger than the foreignObjects, then draw the foreignObjects?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky -- yes, that would be one way of achieving the desired result. I tried applying a linear gradient that went from transparent to black and back to transparent (with stops at 5% and 95%); however, apparently `stroke` cannot take a linear gradient for `path` elements (even though it can for other elements).

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thanks for this suggestion -- the only shortcoming is that it wouldn't work great if it's not possible to match the background (e.g. if the background is patterned). If the background is a solid colour, then this could work, so it at least gives me one possibility. I'll test it out to see how it looks. Thanks for taking the time to read & share your idea, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hope this can help: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14743-multi-colored-lines-in-svg/

Comment: You can get the length of an SVG path via the built in method: getTotalLength() - aka path.getTotalLength()

Comment: it also looks like you're using the cubic .bezierCurveTo but with duplicated control points, so you get that weird hook at the start. In that vein: if you have code problems, remember to [show your code](/help/how-to-ask) (but, of course, in [mcve] form. Your example connects two emoji: omit the code that draws the other ones, etc)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky that link looks amazing: lots to dig in to, really appreciate your taking the time to share it!

Comment: @MichaelMullany thank you -- I'll look into that. I'm not a programmer, by any means, so having a keyword / function to narrow search options is incredibly helpful. I'll be sure to share any solutions I put together, here. Thanks again for taking the time to help; really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans lol -- I'm finding it disproportionately entertaining that everyone who has responded is named "Mike" :D  -- I'm actually not using the cubic here. Just a quadratic with a poorly / randomly chosen control point. I'm trying to set up the code so that a path can be drawn between any two elements in such a way that it will not obstruct other elements in the set, and I was hoping to be able to achieve that without having to calculate a control point for every possible start-end combination.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I considered using the coordinates of another one of the elements as the cntrl point, but that is what has given the mediocre hook. I think I'll just work out 4-5 points on the midline between the ellipses and see if I can set a rule for determining the best choice...

Comment: A quadratic curve wouldn't make sense here: it would be a straight line. You _need_ a cubic if you want something that curves "from" the first "to" the second emoji. You actually _want_ points that don't lie in a straight line, e.g. if the left emoji is at (x1,y1) and the right emoji is at (x2, y2) you want a bezier that is similar to (x1,y1), (x2,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y2). And to then make that look better, you almost certainly want to offset the start/end so that they're offset from the emoji, as well as bring the control points close so you don't have as exaggerated a curve.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think I must be missing something, as the 2nd image in my post shows a first attempt using a quadratic bezier. I eventually switched to a cubic to get more control over the path, but using a quadratic doesn't result in a straight line. The point of my question is more related to the end of your comment: determining an optimal offset *programmatically* so that the line emanates from the emoji in the direction of the destination emoji (i.e. at different hours on the face of a clock, Vs. always leaving from e.g. 3 o'clock).

Comment: quadratic curves can't go "from A to B", they can only make a straight line look curve, so they're utterly useless if you're trying to connect two points in a way that looks aesthetically pleasing. The _only_ way to, as you put it, have "the line emanates from the emoji in the direction of the destination emoji" using beziers is a straight line. What you want instead is to leave "not in the direction of the other emoji" at all: depart straight horizontal, _arrive_ straight horizontal, and use a cubic curve for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: use [de Casteljau algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) twice to trim off the beginning and the end portions of your curve.

Say you were asked to evaluate a cubic Bézier curve defined by the control points C_{0,0}, C_{1,0}, C_{2,0} and C_{3,0} at a particular parameter t between 0 and 1. (I assume that the parameter interval of the curve is [0,1] and I give the control points such strange names in the anticipation of the following. Have a look at the Wikipedia article if you work with a curve degree different from 3.)

You would proceed as follows:

```
for j = 1, ..., 3
  for i = 0, ..., 3 - j
    C_{i, j} = (1 - t) * C_{i, j-1} + t * C_{i+1, j-1}
```

The point C_{0, 3} is the value of your curve at the parameter value t. The whole thing is much easier to understand with a picture (I took t=0.5):

[image: de Casteljau algorithm for a cubic curve]

However, the algorithm gives you more information. For instance, the control points C_{0,0}, C_{0,1}, C_{0,2} and C_{0,3} are the control polygon a curve which is equal to your curve *restricted* to the interval [0, t]; similarly, C_{0,3}, C_{1,2}, C_{2,1} and C_{3,0} give you a Bézier curve equal to your curve restricted to [t, 1]. This means that you can use de Casteljau algorithm to divide your curve in two at a prescribed interval.

In your case, you would:

1. Start with the curve you show in the bottom picture.
2. Use de Casteljau algorithm to split your curve at a parameter t_0 close to 0 (I would start with t_0 = 0.1 and see what happens).
3. Throw away the part defined on [0, t_0] and keep only that defined on [t_0, 1].
4. Take a parameter t_1 close to 1 and split the remaining part from 3.
5. Keep the beginning and throw away the (short) end.

Note that this way you will be splitting you curve according to parameter values and *not* based on its length. If your curves are similar in shape, this is not a problem but if they would differ significantly, you might have to invest some effort at finding suitable values of t_0 and t_1 programmatically.

Another issue is the choice of t_1. I suppose that due to symmetry, you would want to split your curve into [0, t_0], [t_0, 1 - t_0], [1 - t_0, 1]. Taking t_2 = 1 - t_1 would not do, because t_2 refers to the parameter interval of the result of step 3 and that is again *[0, 1]*! Instead, you would need something like t_2 = (1 - t_1)^2.

Comment: This is brilliant! & much closer to what I had in mind (I just can't believe how involved it is), but I never heard of this algorithm, previously. I realized that the masking solution proposed in the comments wouldn't help if I wanted to use markers (which I do). Kind of unfortunate that this kind of flexibility wasn't built into the `path` element: it'd be so nice if you could specify control points and some range for a parameter. I'll give this a shot and see how it goes. Thanks for taking the time to share!

Comment: I'm starting to think it might be easier to programmatically determine the nearest 15-degree angle on a circle ~2px larger than the emoji and just run the cubic bezier between those points. That being said, it might be about as much work, but not quite as nice; just not looking forward to having to figure out how to set the `t` parameter programmatically.

Comment: That would certainly be easier, although I would still recommend to spend some time thinking about de Casteljau, if only to better understand the tools you are using. Yet another option (I'm not sure, if it is viable in you case) would be to draw the objets on top of each other: first the curve, then a white circle bigger than the smiley and only then the smiley.

Comment: Yes, I definitely will consider the _de Casteljau_ approach: your post & the Wiki made the underlying math clear. Your last suggestion about layering is what I started with, but there is no way to use markers, successfully, that I'm aware of, and I'd like to have arrowheads -- so I think I'm stuck with either the clock face approx or _de Casteljau_ I'll follow up here, once I've had a chance to test them out. Thanks again for your time & help!

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution using layers:

- Layer 1: paths;
- Layer 2: elements coloured the same as the background which are slightly larger than the elements layered on top of them (for the emoji, I used circles, for text, I used the same text with a larger pt-size);
- Layer 3: the elements themselves.

### Pros & Cons

Pros:

- quick;
- easy;

Cons:

- can't use `markers` (because they are masked by the background-coloured objects);
- may require some tinkering to find the most appropriate type of background element;

---

Here is a screenshot of a sample output:

[image]